# Launch executable with xdg-open

Tags: file-opening, xdg-open

I am trying to write a function `launchSystemFile` which works like windows `ShellExecuteEx` from the command line or from C++.

If I `ShellExecuteEx` a `blah.txt` it opens it in the default editor.
If I `ShellExecuteEx` a `firefox.exe` it launches the executable.

I have been doing from C++ `popen "xdg-open blah"` and it works great except for executables.

Is there anyway to make `xdg-open` execute an executable? Such as Firefox at path `/usr/lib/firefox/firefox`?

I tried `xdg-open "/usr/lib/firefox/firefox"` but this fails with the error message:

> gvfs-open: /usr/lib/firefox/firefox: error opening location: No application is registered as handling this file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xdg-open` is just a shell script that detects Desktop Environment and call the corresponding program (gvfs-open for gnome , exo-open for XFCE, mate-open, etc.)

So the limitations for launching an executable are derived from the corresponding launcher of each DE, which is gvfs-open in your case.

Looking at [gvfs-open man page](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/gvfs-common/gvfs-open.1.en.html), this app (similar to the other DE apps) just calls the default application registered per file type as it is defined by `gvfs-mime` settings.

In your case , gvfs-open tries (and fails) to find a corresponding application to launch a `firefox file`.

If you run xdg-open (or gvfs-open) with an html link like `https://www.google.com` , then should work correctly; gvfs-open will search mime database to find how to handle the html link, mime will advise to call firefox, and firefox will be called.

Looking at xdg-open shell script functions, there are some functions that extract the `Exec` entry out of the corresponding `.desktop` file and under some Desktop Environments the command found in Exec section of .desktop file is just executed as it is by xdg-open.

In other words, you do not have to call `xdg-open` or `gvfs-open` to launch executables like firefox.

Just launch "firefox" and should be executed (i.e `popen "/usr/bin/firefox"`)

PS: Or you might even need to call `(exec firefox &)`

You could even extract Exec entries by all .desktop files with a grep loop like this:

```bsh
for file in $(find /usr/share/applications/ -type f -name '*.desktop'); do
    executable=$(grep -m1 "^Exec=" "$file") #some files have more than one Exec entry
    echo "$file - $executable"
done
```